# Excel budget w/CC input data

Tags: excel, vba

I am attempting to make a budget calculator and want to import my CC data to compare my actual spending w/estimated spending based on different categories. Briefly, (see attached screen shot), I have the input from my credit card which has location specific data, I have another column with a refined transaction type, and a third and final column with the associated spending category.

I can not figure out how to use the raw transaction data to search for the refined transaction type and associated spending category.

=VLOOKUP(FIND(C2&"*",Sheet3!A:A,1),A1:B10,2,TRUE)

[Problem Example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rpoVU.png)

Comment: Your formula has so many things wrong that it's hard to list them all. You need to strip the numbers from the values in column C, not add a wildcard to the value in column C. Find works on one cell only, not on a column. Find returns the position of the found string in a cell, not a text value.

Comment: got it, thanks for the help.

Answer (score 0):

First of all, the FIND function returns a number, which then becomes a parameter for VLOOKUP. This won't get you the results you're expecting. It'll search for a number.

This is going to be complex but here's a start, for EXACTLY the data you've provided.

```
=VLOOKUP(LEFT(C2,FIND("@",SUBSTITUTE(C2," ","@",(LEN(C2)-LEN(SUBSTITUTE(C2," ","")))/LEN(" ")))-1),A:B,2,0)
```

Drop that into cell D2. Have fun.